# Joining attributes from points to lines QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I am working with two shapefile layers: lines and points. These shapefiles do not overlap and have different attribute values.

[image: example]

The point layer contains data that I want to join to the beginning and end of the line layer. If a can´t join this data by field value or location, which vector tool should I use in QGIS?

Comment: https://imgur.com/0jAO7wb

Comment: Are the layers close enough to each other you could buffer the points and then join attributes by location? Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/336049/edit) your post so it contains the images.

Comment: Hello Erik. The distances between the layers vary throughout the project. In this image the distance is approximately 40 meters. Is buffering still a viable alternative?

Comment: How do you know, which point exactly belongs to a line?

Comment: The point value that I want to add to the beginning and end of each line is the perpendicular of the point (please consider all the points as values from a previous line layer). Each point has a metric value, so there is no problem if different lines have the same value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have tried to set up the example above. I hope I correctly noticed that your point layer consists of points located very close to each other. Looks like the output after using the `'Create points along lines'` tool.

---

I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume we have the following layers *'Layer_Points'* and *'Layer_Lines'*, see image below. The data that has to be transferred from the points placed in the field `"Data"`.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to join points' attributes to lines appropriated through the beginning and the end of the line layer.

```sql
WITH start_points AS (
    SELECT
        l.id,
        p."data"
    FROM
        "Layer_Lines" AS l,
        "Layer_Points" AS p
    GROUP BY
        l.id
    ORDER BY
        MIN(ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(start_point(l.geometry), p.geometry))) DESC
    ),

end_points AS (
    SELECT
        l.id,
        p."data"
    FROM
        "Layer_Lines" AS l,
        "Layer_Points" AS p
    GROUP BY
        l.id
    ORDER BY
        MIN(ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(end_point(l.geometry), p.geometry))) DESC
    )

SELECT
    l.*,
    sp."data" AS "start_data",
    ep."data" AS "end_data"
FROM
    "Layer_Lines" AS l
JOIN start_points AS sp
    ON sp.id = l.id
JOIN end_points AS ep
    ON ep.id = l.id
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: output]

---

[`ST_ShortestLine()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ShortestLine.html)is the shortest line between two geometries. [`ST_StartPoint()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_StartPoint.html) defines the lines' starting points for connecting with points layer, see image below.

[image: start_point]

The same principle was applied for [`ST_EndPoint()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_EndPoint.html)

Answer (score 6):

Use the "Extract specific vertices" tool ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-specific-vertices)) to extract the endpoints of each line as a separate point layer, as explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311643/81764).

Use the [NNJoin plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/) to perform a nearest-neighbor join between the new endpoints layer and your other point layer. Or use the `geomnearest` function from the [refFunctions plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) in the Field Calculator.

Use the Field Calculator to copy the joined values to attributes in your original line layer, with expressions like this:

```
aggregate(
    'endpoints_joined',
    'min',
    "joined_value",
    $geometry = start_point(geometry(@parent))
    )
```

or

```
aggregate(
    'endpoints_joined',
    'min',
    "joined_value",
    $geometry = end_point(geometry(@parent))
    )
```

To apply the example expressions to your data, make the following substitutions:

- Use the actual name of the joined endpoint layer where the example expressions say `'endpoints_joined'`.
- Use the actual name of the field copied from the original point layer where the example expressions say `"joined_value"`.