# Joining attributes from points to polygon

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, line, attribute-joins

I am working with two shapefile, polygons and points. These shapefiles do not overlap and have different attribute values.

The point layer contains data that I want to join to the beginning and end of the polygon layer. Is it possible? (Example below)

[image: example]

[image: example2]

Comment: Software? The join must be done by means of the shortest line?

Comment: If you deploy QGIS there is certainly an interesting article for you [Joining attributes from points to lines QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336049/joining-attributes-from-points-to-lines-qgis/)? Just swap lines with polygons

Comment: qgis 3.8. Join the value of nearest point to a field "beginning" and value of nearest point to another field "end" of the polygon

Comment: Can you please describe more in details `'the beginning and end of the polygon layer'`?

Comment: Did the new image help explain? thanks for the help

Comment: Not really ... it is still not clear to me what sort of lines are they, i.e. a perpendicular, a rhumb line, a polygon extension towards points etc.? Can you clarify it, please?

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384194/88814