# Cluster Points alongside lines with a limit

Tags: qgis, clustering

In QGIS I have a street layer (lines) and a house layer (points) with a start point (red rectangle):

[image]

I want to cluster the points alongside the line layer in groups of 20 or 10 points (I prefer 20).
The result should look like that:

[image]

Each coloured line represents a different cluster. The result was made manually and took a long time, is there any possibility to cluster the points automatically? I only prefer groups of 20 and 10 adresses per line, in some cases I have to use a bit less or more.

Comment: For such questions it would always be good to provide a sample dataset for testing as it takes a while to create a project with layers.

Comment: @Babel ok, how or where can I provice layers in a question?

Comment: You can't upload here. Upload to a cloud and post the link in your question - edit the initial post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Project the points (houses) to the line (streets). Use the following expression or [see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384194/88814): `closest_point (overlay_nearest ('street',$geometry)[0],$geometry)`. Name the resulting point layer as `addresses`.

   *Red points created based on your blue points:*
   [image]
2. Create the shortest path from your start point to each address along the street layer with network tools. Run `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Shortest path (point to layer)`.

   [image]
3. In the resulting line layer (a line for each address/house), calculate how many addresses/houses are on this line. Use this expression to create a new attribute field called `no_of_houses`: `array_length(overlay_nearest ('addresses',$id,limit:=-1,max_distance:=0.01))`
4. Delete features with a value for `no_of_houses` smaller than 20. Keep the ones with `no_of_houses` = 20.
5. Lines with value larger than 20 have to be split up. Select features with `no_of_houses=20` and create the end point of these lines with Geoemtry by expression: `end_point ($geometry)`. Name the resulting layer `end_points`.
6. Use these end points to split the remaining line layers with `no_of_houses < 20` and keep only that part of the line after the end points. Use this expression with Geoemtry by Expression:

   ```
   line_substring (
    $geometry,
    line_locate_point (
        $geometry,
        overlay_nearest('addresses',$geometry)[0]),
    length($geometry)
    )
   ```
7. Repeat step 3 to 7 until no more `no_of_houses` values are larger than 20.
8. Don't forget to delete remaining superfluous lines, resulting in step 6. Use e.g. Delete duplicate geometries.

Comment: thank you for your reply! Sadly I get after the third step every time the total number of addresses and not the number of addresses on a specific line. And before that I don't get a line for each address/house. I am not sure about the first step, I think I made some misstakes there maybe.

Comment: here you can find the concrete Layer examples: https://ln5.sync.com/dl/970d2d420/zp8webf5-hghnis7b-dewfmeug-vdx7saav

Comment: Based on your dataset: be sure to run the expression from step 1 on the layer `Adressen test` and use the name of your street layer, thus with this expression `closest_point (overlay_nearest ('street test',$geometry)[0],$geometry)`. In Geometry by expression, set `Output Geometry Type` to point. See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814 Try this first step and if it doesn't work, describe in detail where you're stuck. Result after step 1 should look like this (red points from you initial blue points): https://i.stack.imgur.com/btKkT.png