# Automatically adding start and end coordinates for output lines created using Graphic Modeller QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a model created using Graphical Modeller that outputs a series of lines. I want to add the x and y coordinates for the start and end points for each line.

I know you can do this once the lines have been created using the field calculator by adding a new field with the following expression `$xat(0)`, `$yat(0)`, `$xat(-1)`, `$yat(-1)`:

[Retrieving start and end points for each line in line shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop or QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146270/retrieving-start-and-end-points-for-each-line-in-line-shapefile-in-arcgis-deskto)

What I would like to do is set this up in Graphic modeller so the line outputs already have the coordinates in the attribute table.

I tried using "Add geometry attributes" but this just gave me the line lengths.

It seems there maybe as solution for ArcGIS as the create field allows an expression to be added.

https://community.esri.com/thread/160829

Is there something similar for QGIS or any other ideas to solve this?

Comment: Just add the expression for the field calculator as an additional part to your model.

Comment: Thank you so much. I must have overlooked it in the algorithm options.